# Validating string input value c language

Tags: input, validating

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char name[10];
 printf("Who are you? \n");
 fgets(name,10,stdin);
 printf("Good to meet you, %s.\n",name);
if(name=='spyros')
   {
    printf("Then you are here %s\n",name)
   } 
 return(0);
}
```

Then i have 
warning  warning: character constant too long for its type

Answer (score 1):

A char can only store 1 character not a set of characters, and by directly comparing the string to a character array won't work because of the null character

This will work , hope it helps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 char name[10];
 printf("Who are you? \n");
 fgets(name,10,stdin);
 printf("Good to meet you, %s.\n",name);
    if(strcmp(name,"spyro"))
   {
    printf("Then you are here %s\n",name);
   } 
 return(0);
}
```